# how to vectorise my code in r using for loop?

Tags: r, foreach

I am trying to run a for loop for the below scenario

I have 100k Unique customers in my transactional table which are going to n number of stores each customer.
I am trying to loop through each customer and seeing in which unique store they are going and if new store has opened within 20 kms range to that store then he/she will go to that store and I will make their Value 1 in new data frame created.
I am initializing my code in first for loop and then repeating the same for rest of my data frame.
My code is extremely slow with for loop. I don't know how to vectorise my code. Below is the snapshot of my code. Please guide me how to make this code faster and efficient.

```
cust_id = c(unique(kk$Customer_ID))
i = cust_id[1]

# for initializing
s = c(0,0,0,0)
df_temp = kk[kk$Customer_ID == i]
store = c(unique(df_temp$Store_Code))

system.time(
for (j in store){
  if(df_temp[Store_Code == j]$dist.km298 < 20) {
    s[1] <- 1
  } 
  if(df_temp[Store_Code == j]$dist.km299 < 20) {
    s[2] <- 1
  } 
  if(df_temp[Store_Code == j]$dist.km300 < 20) {
    s[3] <- 1
  } 
  if(df_temp[Store_Code == j]$dist.km301 < 20) {
    s[4] <- 1
   }

}
```

)

```
vishal <- data.table("Customer_ID" = c(i,i,i,i) , "Store_Code" = 
c(60298,60299,60300,60301), "Prediction" = s)
cust_id <- cust_id[!cust_id %in% c(cust_id[1])]



# loop for all customers
count = 1
system.time(for (k in 1:length(cust_id)){
  i <- cust_id[k]
  # count <- count+1
  # if (count == 5) {
  #   break
  #}
  s = c(0,0,0,0)
  df_temp = kk[kk$Customer_ID == i]
  store = c(unique(df_temp$Store_Code))

  for (j in store){
    #if(df_temp$Store_Code == j & df_temp$Purchase_2016 != 0 & 
df_temp$Purchase_2017 == 0){
    if(df_temp[Store_Code == j]$dist.km298 < 20) {
      s[1] <- 1
    } 
    if(df_temp[Store_Code == j]$dist.km299 < 20) {
      s[2] <- 1
    } 
    if(df_temp[Store_Code == j]$dist.km300 < 20) {
      s[3] <- 1
     } 
    if(df_temp[Store_Code == j]$dist.km301 < 20) {
      s[4] <- 1
    }
  }
  v_temp <- data.table("Customer_ID" = c(i,i,i,i) , "Store_Code" = 
c(60298,60299,60300,60301), "Prediction" = s)
  l =  list(vishal,v_temp)
  vishal <- rbindlist(l)

}

)
dput(head(kk, 5))

structure(list(Customer_ID = 
structure(c(1800000006365760, 1800000006365820,1800000006366060
,1800000006366060,1800000006366060), class = "integer64"), Store_Code = 
c(60067, 60054, 60066, 
60069, 60079), Purchase_2016 = c(2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L), Purchase_2017 = 
c(2L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), TotalPurchases = c(4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L), Return_2016 = 
c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Return_2017 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Return_2010 = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Rp_Ratio_2016 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0), Rp_Ratio_2017 = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0), Sales_Per_Day = c(1699.6, 2101.1, 1331.4, 1813.1, 
1193.1), Store_Launch_Date = structure(c(1323820800, 1322006400, 
1338163200, 1311984000, 1385164800), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"
), tzone = "UTC"), Store_Size_Sq_Ft = c(8673.5, 12425.5, 15897.1, 
6698.1, 3699.5), Customer_Count = c(89351, 118444, 79249, 114246, 
54832), Total_Revenue = c(35350868.4, 43702303, 27693164.7, 37712369.7, 
24816886.2), dist.km298 = c(140.24, 123.87, 10.2, 131.96, 128.52
), dist.km299 = c(163.37, 140.2, 79.32, 153.01, 145.03), dist.km300 = 
c(4.09, 
21.05, 126.55, 7.03, 17.41), dist.km301 = c(5.72, 19.04, 125.46, 
5.02, 15.4), Nationality = c("INDIA", "UNITED ARAB EMIRATES", 
"SRI LANKA", "SRI LANKA", "SRI LANKA"), Gender = c("M", "F", 
"M", "M", "M"), Marital_Status = c("Married", "Married", "Married", 
"Married", "Married"), Loyalty_Status = c("Gold", "Silver", "Silver", 
"Silver", "Silver"), Points = c(814L, 212L, 186L, 186L, 186L), 
Age = c(59L, 119L, 59L, 59L, 59L), LastVisit = c(2, 28, 3, 
3, 3), Last_rdm_txn_dt1 = structure(c(17601, 16510, 17196, 
17196, 17196), class = "Date"), Last_accr_txn_dt1 = structure(c(17801, 
17029, 17774, 17774, 17774), class = "Date")), .Names = c("Customer_ID", 
"Store_Code", "Purchase_2016", "Purchase_2017", "TotalPurchases", 
"Return_2016", "Return_2017", "Return_2010", "Rp_Ratio_2016", 
"Rp_Ratio_2017", "Sales_Per_Day", "Store_Launch_Date", 
"Store_Size_Sq_Ft", 
"Customer_Count", "Total_Revenue", "dist.km298", "dist.km299", 
"dist.km300", "dist.km301", "Nationality", "Gender", "Marital_Status", 
"Loyalty_Status", "Points", "Age", "LastVisit", "Last_rdm_txn_dt1", 
"Last_accr_txn_dt1"), sorted = "Customer_ID", class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -5L), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 
0x0000000004810788>)
```

Comment: Can you post sample data? Please edit **the question** with the output of `dput(kk)`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(kk, 20))`.

Comment: Hi I have done that as suggested by you. Thanyou for guiding me.

Comment: @Rui Barradas can you please answer now ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please read the guide to posting good questions on StackOverflow, it will allow people to answer your questions easily. You question is very confusing but this might give you some ideas:

```
 data %>% 
  group_by(Customer_ID, Store_Code) %>%
  mutate(Predition298 = ifelse(dist.km298 > 20, 1, 0),
         Predition299 = ifelse(dist.km299 > 20, 1, 0),
         Predition300 = ifelse(dist.km300 > 20, 1, 0))
```

Comment: I want to iterate through each customer and the stores where he/she visited and then impute Predition298 ,Predition299 .....so on with either 0 or 1.

Comment: Ok, without the dataset it's nearly impossible to help... maybe use group_by(Costomer_ID, Store_Code) before mutate but its hard to tell

Comment: I have provided dataset please find it in my code by scrolling down in code window.